# Local hidden variable field and null pointer exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm getting a warning in my IDE (Java NetBeans) and an error when running, and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

The warning is about a hidden field by a local variable and I just want to create a boolean array of 65536 bits.

```
public class Main
{
    private static boolean[] BusyDevices ;
    
    /* main entry point */
    public static void main(String argv[])
    {

       boolean BusyDevices[]=new boolean[65536];//<-Here the warning
       
    }
       
    public static boolean isDeviceBusy(String deviceIDx)
    {
        if(deviceIDx.length()>4 || deviceIDx.length()<4)
        {
            return false;
        }
       
        try
        {
            return BusyDevices[Integer.parseInt(deviceIDx, 16)];
        }
        catch(Exception e)            
        {
            Print.logException("Error deviceIDx:" + deviceIDx, e);           
            return false;
        }       
    }     
}
```

I think that I'm doing something wrong when resizing the boolean array; Or can be a conversion error?
Plus I need to start with all bits in false state, That's the default state right?.

Comment: You're creating a new local variable with the same name as your class level variable. Remove the first `boolean` from inside your `main()` method. And yes, the array will be initialized to all `false`.

Answer (score 2):

You have two variables with the same name `BusyDevices` because of which this issue is happening, Since the class level variable is conflicting with the `main` method variable.

Try to change the variable name in the below line:

```
 boolean BusyDevices[]=new boolean[65536];//<-Here the warning
```

as

```
 BusyDevices=new boolean[65536];//No duplicate variable now, variable type declation is not required
```

Comment: I don't want two variables with the same name, I just want to initialize a boolean array of 65536 bits.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are declaring a static field of the class `Main` called `BusyDevices`

```
private static boolean[] BusyDevices ;
```

Here you are declaring a local variable with the same name in the static method `main` of the class `Main`

```
boolean BusyDevices[]=new boolean[65536];
```

In such a case the local variable declaration takes precedence and "hides" or "shadows" the field of the class

You probably intended to do this, to initialize the field (instead of a local variable)

```
BusyDevices = new boolean[65536];
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I want, thanks. The parseint is ok? I'm going to send four digits hexadecimal numbers.